# Vpn service to log iOS internet usage?

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, monitoring, time-tracking

I want a service like rescueTime for iOS. I'm pretty sure apps can't look at other app usage directly, but I think a vpn could track most of my usage, as I mostly do stuff that requires an internet connection. Are there any vpn's that have iOS apps that could summarize my usage?

Answer (score 1):

I believe My Data Manger would solve your problem. ;)

Comment: That looks pretty close to what I want, but it seems to only have per app data usage reports for ios 6. I'd really like something where I could just tag domains as productive, nonproductive, neutral, etc and have it generate graphs. This seems aimed at tracking when you reach a cap, not where you're spending your time.

Comment: Hum well it does give you the data AND Wi-Fi usage, I actually used it already with ios 9 and it gives me the data and wifi used by each app, so I think the only thing that you won't get is the groups but I don't think any app, with VPN or not will be able to track the time you spend on each app because of iOS' sandbox, also if it tracked by the data or wifi usage it would be extremely inaccurate.

Comment: Huh, ok. I guess their faq is just outdated. Thanks. I'll give it a go

Comment: But remember I USED to use it, past.  Because using a VPN is extremely inaccurate. I then checked with my carrier's app and I had a difference of 70 MB